# where to look if app crashes on startup

Tags: android

I am a beginner to android. in java and other programming languages we get error in the console. how to find the same as if there is no error in the code and app crashes on start up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the logcat in eclipse, red lines are errors. Double click on them shows you the line in code where the error comes from (try all of them ).

Comment: maybe it is in the middle of the red lines, try anyone. If it does not jump plt post all your red lines

Comment: 06-15 17:35:18.240: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1356) This is one of the many errors

Comment: 06-15 17:35:18.240: E/AndroidRuntime(341): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-15 17:35:18.240: E/AndroidRuntime(341): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: QNA: , while compiling: SELECT KID, KQ, KA FROM QNA
06-15 17:35:18.240: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
06-15 17:35:18.240: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
06-15 17:35:18.240: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)

Comment: yes two of them were clickable  thanks for the help and patience  Boe-Dev

Answer (score 1):

Error messages that occur on the device [will be visible to you via LogCat](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html#logcat), accessible by the `adb logcat` command, the LogCat pane in standalone DDMS, or the LogCat view in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

You can always Check the LogCat Console in DDMS Perspective